# HTTP/1.1 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE получение ответа от Яндекс переводчика. Java

Tags: java, запрос, http-post

Ошибка получения ответа на запрос перевода текста в Яндекс переводчик:

> HTTP/1.1 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE [Server: nginx/1.6.2, Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 0, Connection: keep-alive,
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=120, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Date: Sun,
>   16 Oct 2016 09:57:17 GMT]
>   org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@4250f136

```
public String request(String str, String key, String lang) throws Exception{
  @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "deprecation" })
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(PATH);
  httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", lang));     
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("format", "html"));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", str));  
  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, Consts.UTF_8));

  HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost); 

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse
          .getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

 //System.out.println(br.readLine());
  String string = br.readLine();

  return string;

}
```

Предполагаю, что нужно увеличить таймаут ожидания от сервера, но не знаю как.
Запрос формируется правильно так как ошибка возникает только для некоторых текстов на перевод.

Comment: А то, что сервис действительно может быть в этот момент недоступен (о чём и сообщает)  не рассматривается?

Comment: Нет так как он для определенного текста постоянно недоступен, а если другой отправить то все ок.

Comment: А если другими путями тот же текст передать? `wget -qO - "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=$key&text=$text&lang=ru"`

Comment: Мне бы подробней, что куда написать с примером.

Comment: Да просто в командной строке запустить `wget` (если windows - гуглить "wget для windows"), вместо `$key` - ваш ключ, вместо `$text` - текст. Желательно к параметрам `-qO -` добавить `-S`.

Comment: Вот такой подход, как во втором ответе ( от RealMan) на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764035/apache-httpclient-timeout - не подойдет?